# Referencing mistake in masters dissertation

Tags: citations

I handed in my masters dissertation a few weeks ago and I’ve now discovered a referencing mistake in my literature review. A medical publication I’d been citing has had a number of updates over the years and instead of citing the earlier year (2009) I’ve cited 2018. I could kick myself. I’m very anxious about this and not sure if I should just wait it out or speak to my advisor? I had mentioned to him that I couldn’t stop re reading it (before I realised about the year thing and he told me stop it and I wish I had listened. I realise that nothing can be done to rectify it and I’m willing to accept I’ll lose marks if found but I’m worried something more serious will happen. I’m so mortified and hoped to apply for a PhD next year ( I was on track for a first) I honestly can’t believe I’ve made such a careless mistake. Marks are due out at the end of Nov.

Comment: If you are feeling very anxious you should discuss that with a mental health professional.

Comment: What's your question?

Comment: So the only issue is that the year of publication for a single reference is incorrect?

Comment: No I’ve used the source a few times and cited them all as 2018.

Comment: It’s referenced in the ref list as 2018 so I guess the only way it will be flagged at this stage is if they check the quotes or if the marker is very familiar with the guidelines and realises the mistake. I’m more concerned it will be picked up later if someone chooses to read it from the share folder in the library - not that I think it would be widely read but my advisor does circulate previous dissertations so that students can get an idea of structure etc.

Comment: I'm not very clear regarding what the issue actually is: You don't cite the first edition but a later edition of a book? How is that something you need to worry about?

Comment: Because it’s a medical publication it updates every few years. The direct quotes I cited can be found in the 2009 guidelines - they were adjusted and some were removed for the 2018 edition (the year I gave after the quote). Therefore, if you attempted to look up the direct quotes they can no longer be found on the 2018 edition. Maybe I’m making more of it that needs be, my university is very strict re referencing and I’m pretty annoyed at myself for making such a careless mistake.

Answer (score 1):

I don't have enough reputation to comment but we are all human and we make mistakes, you could ask your advisor about submitting an erratum but it is generally done only for peer-reviewed publications.

Personally, I wouldn't worry too much about a typo in my citations. Unless the entire conclusions of a section really depended on the results from this particular reference.

Comment: Thanks, it’s part of my literature review so not directly related to my thoughts/conclusions.

Answer (score -1):

Your school may have a procedure for submitting updates/corrections to your dissertation.  This will probably require contacting the committee who reviewed the original work, and also the library that archives copies of the dissertation.

This citation error, however, is pretty minor, and while you reference a newer copy instead of the old, most researchers may figure it out from context.

Comment: Thank you, although I don’t think this happens at masters level at my university. I think if it’s not picked up at marking I will suggest to my advisor that I spotted a mistake and can I put an update on it?